# How to show bottom navigation bar in page that is not in the navigation item list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 6 pages(just for example but actually more for big app) for my app and I think that only 4 items in bottom navigation bar is more than enough. So that I put page 1 to 4 in navigation bar and navigation correctly.

So I need to go to another two more pages, page 5 and page 6.

These two page can go from page 4. I will use page 4 like menu. Ok, my question is how to put bottom navigation bar on page 5 and page 6.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how to start the app from page 5 or 6 (you can comment if i'm wrong).

If you use `PageView`, you should just change the index of your navigation bar, you can set your `selectedIndex` variable to 4 if you want to start with page 5, like that :

```
int _selectedIndex = 4;
```

And If you wanted to have the first icon to be page 5, you can just change the order of your `PageView`, like that :

```
body: PageView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
            children: [
              const Page4(),
              const Page5(),
              const Page1()
              const Page2()
            ]),
```

Here, the pages are other fonctions (files), but it can work anyway you want (for exemple if you use containers you can also do it, the method is the same).

Comment: Hi Ghali Skalli,
I have a button to navigate to page 5 and page 6, in page 4. That is last item in bottom  navigation bar. My idea is that I want to use page 4 like menu. When I click page 5 on page 4, it will show page 5 but I don't how to show bottom navigation bar for page 5 and so on. 
I will check PageView. Thanks for reply.

Comment: you can try to make 2 bottom navigation bar (child of page 4).